# Getting Unhandled RunTime Error when trying to 'Save'

Tags: typescript, runtime-error

```
Error: Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Image"

Source

lib/utils.ts (18:10) @ handleError

  16 |   // This is a native JavaScript error (e.g., TypeError, RangeError)
  17 |   console.error(error.message);
> 18 |   throw new Error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
     |        ^
  19 | } else if (typeof error === "string") {
  20 |   // This is a string error message
  21 |   console.error(error);

Call Stack

error
  lib/actions/image.actions.ts (91:16)

async ImageDetails
  app/(root)/transformations/[id]/page.tsx (15:16)
```

I am unsure how to fix this issue, every time I try to click save I get this error

Comment: Is this for TypeScript?  You should probably add the relevant language tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.